# (assigning max=0 and min=1000) and it still prints out the right result. Someone please explain how it works

Tags: shell-script

```bsh
#This function is used to generate random number between (0-100)
function RandomGen {
  for i in {0..4}; do
    arr[i]=$[$RANDOM%100]
    echo Random Number $[$i+1] is ${arr[i]}
  done
}

#This function is used to identify and display Highest and lowest number among generated random number.
function HighLow {
  max=0 # ${arr[0]}
  min=1000 # ${arr[0]}
  for i in {1..4}; do
    if [[ "${arr[i]}" -gt "$max" ]]; then
      let "max = arr[i]"
    fi
    if [[ "${arr[i]}" -lt "$min" ]]; then
      let "min = arr[i]"
    fi
  done
  echo "Highest and lowest number among those random numbers are: $max and $min respectively."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: because at the start, `max` is the lowest possible number and `min` is higher than the largest possible number.

This is a simple algorithm to find the low and high in the array. Because it is only 4 iterations, you should be able to just write it out on paper to see what is happening. Alternatively, you can put lots of echos in the loop to see what is happening. For example:

```
max=0 # ${arr[0]}
min=1000 # ${arr[0]}
for i in {1..4}; do
    echo "Iteration $i: min=$min, max=$max"
    if [[ "${arr[i]}" -gt "$max" ]]; then
        echo "Found that ${arr[$i]} > $max"
        let "max = arr[i]"

    fi
    if [[ "${arr[i]}" -lt "$min" ]]; then
        echo "Found that ${arr[$i]} <$min"
        let "min = arr[i]" 
    fi
done
echo "Highest and lowest number among those random numbers are: $max and $min respectively."
```

This will give you

```
Random Number 1 is 23
Random Number 2 is 19
Random Number 3 is 92
Random Number 4 is 42
Random Number 5 is 12
Iteration 1: min=1000, max=0
Found that 19 > 0
Found that 19 <1000
Iteration 2: min=19, max=19
Found that 92 > 19
Iteration 3: min=19, max=92
Iteration 4: min=19, max=92
Found that 12 <19
Highest and lowest number among those random numbers are: 92 and 12 respectively.
```

What would go wrong, is if you assigned 1000 to `max` at the beginning.

--- edit --

I missed the fact that you fill from `i=0` to `4` and loop over  `i=1` to `4`.

If you loop over `0` to `4`, my answer is still correct.

However, otherwise, your loop will only examine `arr[1]` to `arr[4]`. If the minimum and the maximum is in this part of the array, the answer will be correct. However, if `arr[0]` is either the minimum or the maximum, with your fixed `min` and `max` values, `arr[0]` will not be examined, and you will miss the minimum or maximum.

In my example, `arr[0]` is 23, which is larger than the minimum 19, and therefore, the answer is correct.